# Java file not compiling

Tags: java, package

Currently trying to work with objects in Java. Everything goes fine until I hit compile. Have been reading a couple of other questions regarding the same problem, or the same given error, and at this point I am not sure wether I am forgetting something or that I need to change my classpath.

Main Class file:

```
package TesterClass;

public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        TesterClass firstTest  = new TesterClass();
        firstTest.stringPrinter();
    }
}
```

The file that is supposed to be functioning as a package file:

```
package TesterClass;

public class TesterClass{

    private String workingSegment;

    public TesterClass(){
        workingSegment = "Working";
    }

    public void stringPrinter(){
        System.out.println(workingSegment);
    }
}
```

The 2 files are in the same directory and I am trying to manually compile them with 
"javac Tester.java". The error I get is about the fact that its having issues with the package. All help is welcome!

EDIT: Forgot to post the actual compiler error.

```
Tester.java:9: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TesterClass
location: class TesterClass.Tester
        TesterClass firstTest;
        ^
Tester.java:11: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TesterClass
location: class TesterClass.Tester
            firstTest = new TesterClass();
                        ^
2 errors
```

Comment: Can you paste the error message or stacktrace here?

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: Move back to the top of the package branch (`..`) and try recompiling using `javac TesterClass/Tester.java`

Comment: Added the compiler error, sorry my bad!

Comment: As @MadProgrammer says -- compile from the root of your source-folder, if you try to compile from "within" a package then `javac` doesn't understand your package structure. Package names are also meant to be lowercase by convention & should not just mimic the classnames. Try "scratch", "test", "work" as package names. Real systems use package names like "myAccounts.customer", "myAccounts.product", "myAccounts.order" or perhaps "myPDF.reader", "myPDF.display" or perhaps "game.monsters", "game.map", "game.player".

Comment: @MadProgrammer Tried it and still gives me the same error if I javac the file from one directory lower.

Comment: Compile both files...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Tried compiling them both...

Comment: Are both files in the `TestClass` directory?  Do they live together or are they in separate directories?  Cause I just tried compiling your code without issue

Answer (score 3):

Move to the top of the source tree and compile both class...

So, assuming you source files are in `\Java\TesterClass`, you need to start in `\Java`

```
javac TesterClass\Tester.java TesterClass\TesterClass.java
```

You may also want to have a quick read of [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) as packages names are suppose to be in lower case :P

**Updated**

I just tried...

```
javac TesterClass\Tester.java
```

And it worked fine.

Are you sure that the `Tester.java` and `TesterClass.java` are in the `TesterClass` directory?

**Updated with running example**

So, basically, I dropped you `.java` files into the directory `\compile` under the `TesterClass` (`\compile\TesterClass`) directory and compiled them using...

```
\compile>javac TesterClass\Tester.java
```

Then I run them...

```
\compile>java TesterClass.Tester
Working
```

Comment: Currently both files compiled successfully. Only problem now is that I am getting an error when I am trying to run the file

Comment: What exact error do you get when you try to execute your `Tester` class?!

Comment: It is telling me "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test/Tester (wrong name: TesterClass/Tester)"

Comment: @KiptScriddy `Test/Tester` isn't where the class files exist, they should exist in `Tester`.  Take a look at the updates

Comment: Why isnt it working when I try to run it in the folder itself as " java Tester"? Not really understanding where the problem atm is

Comment: Packages are Java's name space mechanism.  That means that the package name is meaningful to the class name.  This allows you to have multiple classes named the same, but in different packages.  This means you can't just "run" a class from within it's package, because Java will want the class NOT to have a package name, this will cause a `wrong name` exception.  Instead, you need to move to the root of the package and use the fully qualified name of the class to run it.

Comment: Okay so typing in "java Testerclass/Tester" while in the root folder of the package file should do the trick?

Comment: @KiptScriddy No, it should be `java TesterClass.Tester`, assuming `dir TesterClass` lists all the `.java` and `.class` files from your current location...

Comment: Okay. I renamed the package differently so that the class name and the package don't have the same name. But it is still giving me the same error :(

Comment: Did you rename the `package` decelerations in the `.java` file and recompile them?

Comment: Yes I did. In both of the files. It's now a file with filename in lowercase.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the names (package.class) please

Comment: Ofcourse! I renamed my package file to testpackage.java , within is the class named TesterClass. The other remained the same, with exception the package filename at the beginning of the file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39393/discussion-between-madprogrammer-and-kipt-scriddy)

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the top of the directory hierarchy and first compile your `TesterClass` and then compile your `Tester`. Since you have not compiled your `TesterClass` yet, `Tester` is unable to find it.

The error clearly states that its not able to find the symbol `TesterClass`, and the reason being `TesterClass` hasn't been compiled yet.

I suggest you use an IDE which does the compilation automatically for you. If you stick to manual compilation, you need to compile *all* the classes in the *proper* order.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the package name so it does not match the class name. Right now they are the same. Make it package TesterClassPackage, then import TesterClass into the file with the main() method.  Even though they are in the same package sometimes you need to literally import files even though they are in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

javac TesterClass\TesterClass.java TesterClass\Tester.java

will do it